# enable to start user profile synchronization service sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

i try to start user prole synchronization service sharepoint 2013
it's stuck on starting statut 
i try :
-stop and restart the service via sharepoint power shell 
-delete the user profile application, restart the server and create a new one the problem still the same

Answer (score 0):

This is a very helpful article: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx

Same steps for 2010 and 2013.